# Difference between "Save As PNG" and "Save For Web" in Photoshop CS5

Tags: adobe-photoshop, export, png, cs5

I saved a PSD file as a PNG file through the `File > Save As...` option and then through the Save for Web and Devices option as PNG-24 format.

Is it safe to say that the first way of doing it is already PNG-24 format, since I compared both and they look similar although the file size isn't exactly the same? I have no other bit choices other than PNG-8 format to compare, and that obviously looks different from the PNG saved using the first method.

Answer (score -1):

You can check by right checking the details of the saved file. In Windows the example is to right click, select `properties` and go to the `details` tab. You'll see the `Bit depth` as one of the details in the attached screenshot.

[image: PNG image details]